How to change the suggested filename when trying to save a website as PDF?
When trying to save a website as PDF ( via ctrl + P ) the browser is suggesting a filename. My web app is embedded inside an iFrame. Chrome suggests the following

...iframe source url....pdf

When using Firefox the suggested filename is

productName.pdf

I don't know where this data is coming from but I would like to set my own filename suggestion ( across all common browsers ). Is that possible with JavaScript? I'm looking for something like
addEventListener("beforeprint", (event) => {
  // change suggested filename to `foo.pdf` in Browser UI
});


It's likely based on the document.title but each browser may be using something else if this isn't set, eg the url.

so there is no way to overwrite this behaviour =?

Did you try setting the document.title of the iframe content?
